# Vectorizing Multi-Dimensional Operations in Python

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I am wondering if vectorization can be applied to two vector inputs at once...

Consider the following simple function:

```
def f(x,y):
    return(x+y,x-y)
```

I want to give a function like this, two vectors `x=arange(3)` and `y=arange(4,6)`. 
My instinct is to define `a,b=f(x,y)` but python tells me that `these operators could not be broadcast with shapes (3) (2)`. Clearly this works if `y` (or `x`) were scalars.

Whats the way to do this? Is there one?

Comment: and what results do you want to receive for x=arange(3) and y=arange(4,6)?

Answer (score 1):

This will work fine, if the dimensions of the vectors x and y are the same.
You have the following code setup:

```
In [16]: x=arange(3)

In [17]: x
Out[17]: array([0, 1, 2])

In [18]: y=arange(4,6)

In [19]: y
Out[19]: array([4, 5])
```

Obviously, x+y are not defined. Since x has 3 entities (dimensions) and y has only 2.

Consider a slight modification:

```
In [21]: y=arange(4,7)

In [22]: x+y
Out[22]: array([4, 6, 8])

In [23]: x-y
Out[23]: array([-4, -4, -4])
```

Now, x+y and x-y work as expected.

Now your function will also work fine.

```
In [24]: def f(x,y):
....:     return (x+y,x-y)
....: 

In [25]: f(x,y)
Out[25]: (array([4, 6, 8]), array([-4, -4, -4]))
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I should have mentioned that I indeed do want element wise operations. So it should not matter that I give it inconsistent matrices x and y (in fact x and y are `N-by-5-by-5 and I want to write this to to do matrix operations for each of the 5-by-5 matrices).